# Django - Avoid duplicates in many to many intermediate model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm writing a simple application with the models `Person` and `Project`, which have a many to many relationship through the `Membership` model. Only one `Membership` can exist between any two given `Person` and `Project` objects. Currently, new `Membership` objects can be added via inline from both the `Person` and `Project` change forms.

This works fine, but there's the problem of a user accidentally creating a redundant `Membership`. I've set a `unique_together` constraint for the two foreign keys in the `Membership` model, however this has two problems:

1. When saving a new parent object, any redundant instances of the `Membership` model are saved without raising any kind of error.
2. When modifying an existing object, adding a redundant `Membership` triggers the expected error message, but the delete icon of the corresponding inline is not shown and it's not possible to remove one of the objects that have already been persisted because the error prevents any database operations from happening.

I'd like to know what's the right way of iterating through the `membership_set` collection before the parent object is saved and removing any redundant objects.

Comment: Something else must be going wrong. `unique_together` is a database-level constraint, there's simply nothing you can do in Django that will result in redundant rows being created. So if you're seeing redundant rows the problem is that your `unique_together` isn't working correctly. Are you sure you `migrated` the change and it's been applied to the database? Can you look at your database and confirm that the constraint exists? Can you actually see the duplicated rows that you think have been created?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, turns out I hadn't run the corresponding migrations. However, now when I save a new parent object I get a server exception instead of a validation error, so I still have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I made in my project:

```
#Models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

The view

```
#views.py
class GroupDetails(generic.DetailView):

model = Group
template_name = 'app/template.html'
form_class = SomeForm

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form = self.form_class(request.POST)

       #get group
       group = self.get_object(queryset=Group.objects.all())

       #get person
       person = Person.objects.get(pk=request.user)

       #check if objects exists before save
       if Membership.objects.filter(person = person, group = group).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'Oh this is duplicated')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view-name', kwargs={'pk': group.pk}))

       else:

          if form.is_valid():
              form.save(commit=False)

              #assign to the through table
              persontogroup = Membership.objects.create(person = person, group = group)

              persontogroup.save()

              messages.success(request, 'Success!')

       return HttpResponseRedirect('/something/')
```

Hope this helps. You can also check: [Avoid Django def post duplicating on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608903/avoid-django-def-post-duplicating-on-save)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I'm using the default Admin interface. I think the link you provided could help, so I'll check it out and let you know.